# Heroku update says I don't have the toolbelt

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface

I have a Rails project that is using heroku_san for deployment. I wanted to give heroku's new toolbelt a shot, so I installed it on my system, which is a Mac Os X, and ran heroku upgrade and I am getting this message:

> `heroku update` is only available from Heroku Toolbelt.
>
> Download and install from https://toolbelt.heroku.com

I already have it installed, though.

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/heroku` exist? What's its permissions?

Comment: Yes, it does. Its permissions are: `lrwxr-xr-x`

Comment: Do you have the heroku gem installed?

Comment: I do, but I also tried uninstalling it. Problem is heroku_san depends on the heroku gem so I got Bundler gem errors.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I removed the gem but heroku version still shows heroku-gem/3.8.4 (x86_64-darwin12.5.0) ruby/2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

The following steps worked for me:

1. download and install toolbelt: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/
2. in terminal, "gem uninstall heroku", and then choose "all versions" if you have multiple.

you mentioned you have a gem that depends on the heroku gem, so I'm not sure what to tell you besides to try to eliminate that dependency.